# How to launch help pages from new-style Oracle Java OSX bundle structure?

Tags: java, macos, swing

A few versions of Java ago it was possible to launch Apple help for a Swing app by bundling it up right, e.g. using `JarBundler` to compile a stub.  I've now switched to using Oracle's `appbundler` (actually Infinitekind's [fork](https://bitbucket.org/infinitekind/appbundler)) as this seems to be the only way to get the app to look sharp on Retina screens, and also is presumably the way things are going.

Is there a way to bundle up launchable help pages using `appbundler`? ([Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) doesn't mention anything).

Or is it now a matter of putting help pages in the right place in the bundle?

I should make it clear that I'm not using XCode and do not plan to, although if there's a one-time solution involving it, naturally I will.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the horrible hack I found.

I have three ingredients:

1. A recent version of Infinitekind's appbundler fork that allows `plistentry`s.
2. A folder of HTML help pages in a folder called `onlinehelp` in `${resource.dir}`
3. An old compiled helpbook launch stub called `libHelpBookJNI.jnilib` in 
   `${resource.dir}`

where did that launch stub come from?  From compiling this

```
#import <JavaVM/jni.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_edu_harvard_wcfia_yoshikoder_HelpBook_launchHelpViewer (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz) {
[[NSApplication sharedApplication]] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showHelp:) withObject:NULL waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

which worked back in Java 1.6 days, and apparently still does.  My old ant task for compiling that looks like this:

```
<target name="jni"
      description="Compile the JNI bridge that launches OSX help">
<exec executable="cc">
  <arg line="-c"/>
  <arg line="-I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers"/>
  <arg line="-o HelpBookJNI.o"/> 
  <arg value="src/objc/HelpBookJNI.m"/>
</exec>
<exec executable="cc">
  <arg line="-dynamiclib"/>
  <arg line="-framework JavaVM"/>
  <arg line="-framework Cocoa"/>
  <arg line="-o libHelpBookJNI.jnilib"/>
  <arg value="HelpBookJNI.o"/>   
</exec>
<delete file="HelpBookJNI.o" quiet="true"/> 
</target>
```

With that elderly and doubtless fragile library compiled, I manually insert files in the the relevant places in the app bundle.

```
<bundleapp ...>
  ...
  <plistentry key="CFBundleHelpBookFolder" value="Help"/>
  <plistentry key="CFBundleHelpBookName" value="Yoshikoder Help"/>
</bundleapp>

<copy todir="Yoshikoder.app/Contents/Resources/Help/">
  <fileset dir="onlinehelp" includes="**/*" />
</copy>
<copy file="${resource.dir}/libHelpBookJNI.jnilib"
      todir="Yoshikoder.app/Contents/Java/" />
```

If this looks like I'm making things up as I go along, it's because I'm making things up as I go along.  But it does work on this Mac running Yosemite with the Java 1.8 JDK (plus Apple's own zombie Java 1.6)